# Firebase Auth, get a User UID before the user registers

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am developing an invitation mechanism to our app. New users will be invited with their e-mail addresses or their telephone numbers. I would like to keep some records about the invited but non-registered user. So, I want to have their Firebase Auth User UID before they even signed up. Is this possible? Maybe using Firebase Admin SDK?

I don't want to use their e-mail addresses or telephone numbers to refer to them because UID feels like a better identifier. However, UID is not there before they sign up, right?

We toyed with creating a user and generating a passwordless login for them, etc. But whatever we do seems to mess with the initial sign up of users. It would be great if we could just get a UID and let the user sign up later.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/57663477/1164465

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a user account, and then have the user "sign up" with the same UID. So you will have to handle your "sign up" flow a little differently.

In [this demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hlxby1Mmic8) an administrator creates a user account, and then invites the user to sign in by sending them an authentication code (jump ahead to the 3:00 minute mark in the recording). Then the user is allowed to sign in and activate their account by presenting the authentication code.

You can try to build something similar. For example you can save a flag for each new user in the database, and then clear that flag in a custom sign up action.